# Getting success message from a form that posts data to google spreadsheet

Tags: forms, html

I have been developing a form and have linked it to the Google Docs spreadsheet. So when a user enters details it goes straight to the spreadsheet and populates it. I took the advice from this bit of code here;

http://mashe.hawksey.info/2011/10/google-spreadsheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-form-postget-submit-method

It works perfectly here: http://betaburo.markdunbavan.co.uk

My only problem is that I want to create a success message and error messages.

There is a bit of code in the main.js file that basically validates it but it is not working or recognising the errors or the success.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery you can check to see that something has been entered. There are a couple ways to do this.

For example, if you wanted to validate your first name field you could do:

```
if ($('input#field1').val() == ''){
       $('span.successMessage').hide();
       $('span.errorMessage').show();
       }
else {
       $('span.successMessage').show();
       $('span.errorMessage').hide();
     }
```

You could also use .serialize on the input, then display the success/error message depending on the length of the serialized entry (i.d. use .length on the serialized entry).

Comment: Ah okay, I see what you mean. If I wanted to create a thank you box as well this would use a similar approach to the jquery above right? So the user would enter all details and it would call something like

Comment: sorry pressed enter ...this but on all fields being a success?

Comment: yeah, if and else if to check that all the boxes are filled, then in the else have your success message